# Problem running ClickOnce application in Windows 10 multi-app kiosk mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, kiosk-mode

I’m trying to set up a Windows 10 multi-app kiosk configuration running a ClickOnce application. I’m following the Microsoft guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps

It works until the ClickOnce application is updated after this it’s not possible run the application.

The problem is the path *C:\Users\Musikspelare\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\EBQ78BLC.1MN\0J3M24G5.KRQ\danc..tion_57ca62a9d061b04b_0002.0000_6fffc994766df618\DancePlayer.exe* to the ClickOnce application under the  section as this path changes after the application is updated.

Is there any other way of doing this for a ClickOnce application?

The XML configuration file for the multi-app kiosk setup looks as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AssignedAccessConfiguration
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/2017/config"
    xmlns:rs5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/201810/config"
    >
    <Profiles>
        <Profile Id="{AFF9DA33-AE89-4039-B646-3A5706E92957}">
            <AllAppsList>
                <AllowedApps>
                    <App AppUserModelId="SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic_zpdnekdrzrea0!Spotify"/>
                    <App DesktopAppPath="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"/>
                    <App DesktopAppPath="C:\Users\Musikspelare\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\EBQ78BLC.1MN\0J3M24G5.KRQ\danc..tion_57ca62a9d061b04b_0002.0000_6fffc994766df618\DancePlayer.exe"/>
                </AllowedApps>
            </AllAppsList>
            <StartLayout>
    <![CDATA[<LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
      <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
      <DefaultLayoutOverride>
        <StartLayoutCollection>
          <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">
            <start:Group Name="">
              <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic_zpdnekdrzrea0!Spotify" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="3" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\DancePlayer\DancePlayer.appref-ms" />
            </start:Group>
          </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
        </StartLayoutCollection>
      </DefaultLayoutOverride>
    </LayoutModificationTemplate>
    ]]> 
            </StartLayout>
            <Taskbar ShowTaskbar="true"/>
        </Profile>
    </Profiles>
    <Configs>
        <Config>
            <Account>Musikspelare</Account>
            <DefaultProfile Id="{AFF9DA33-AE89-4039-B646-3A5706E92957}"/>
        </Config>
    </Configs>
</AssignedAccessConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue. Fortunately, multi-app kiosk mode utilizes AppLocker to allow the apps listed under the "AllowedApps" tag. You can use an asterisk (*) as a wildcard in your filepaths to include arbitrary paths that are generated from ClickOnce applications. You would make the following adjustment to your code:

```
<App DesktopAppPath="%OSDrive%\Users\Musikspelare\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\*\danc..tion_57ca62a9d061b04b_0002.0000_6fffc994766df618\DancePlayer.exe"/>
```

You should also include the AMUID of the app as it's listed from the Get-StartApps cmdlet to the "AllowedApps" list.

I haven't been able to test whether the AMUID looking portion of that path, "danc..tion_57ca62a9d061b04b_0002.0000_6fffc994766df618" is generated as part of the install or if it's a GUID. It may also change when the ClickOnce apps updates, if that's the case, just remove that portion from the path and it should take care of it.

And for anybody using Intune, I wasn't able to include an asterisk in the path for a multi-app setup under the Kiosk Template. You will have to create a profile that includes the AssignedAccess policy and add your own XML.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/assignedaccess-csp